# Why might my model be learning to always predict 4 objects?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, object-detection-api

I have fine-tuned an object detection model based on `ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_coco` from the tensorflow model zoo: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md

My fine-tuned model always predicts 4 objects, regardless of the input image.

**What might cause the model to learn to always predict exactly 4 objects?**

I have verified that my training data has a wide range of the number of objects in the images. I have tried using the default configuration file inside the zip of the base model as well as the one checked into github here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs. Both produced the same result.

My pipeline configuration files are based on the defaults for the `ssd_mobilenet_v2_quantized_coco` model from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md or https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs. No modifications besides filling in the relevant local paths and using my custom label map.

I expect that my model should be able to predict between 0-100 objects. Instead it always predicts 4.

Example output:
(label): (confidence)

Image 1 (all wrong):

```
STATIONARY_CAR: 0.0820312
PERSON: 0.0820312
PERSON: 0.0585938
STATIONARY_CAR: 0.0585938
```

Image 2 (car correct, rest wrong):

```
STATIONARY_CAR: 0.992188
PERSON: 0.0898438
PERSON: 0.0585938
PERSON: 0.0585938
```

Image 3 (all correct):

```
STATIONARY_CAR: 0.910156
STATIONARY_CAR: 0.910156
STATIONARY_CAR: 0.867188
STATIONARY_CAR: 0.613281
```

Comment: It seems that classification-wise and confidence-wise your model is doing great since there's a one to one match between correct classifications to high confidence. You didn't post your inference code, but it seems like there's some filter on the results which takes only the top-4.

Comment: You need to set a score threshold for [post-processing](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/4909765543ff0c96627161ecc75eec6c309dbdce/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_quantized_300x300_coco14_sync.config#L131), setting `score_threshold= 0.6` can help filter out some wrong detections.